# Настройка samba на ubuntu server

Tags: windows, samba, share, ubuntu

У меня тема курсового проекта по сетям "Настройка Ubuntu Server для локальной сети".

Пытаюсь настроить samba (файловый сервер) для расшаривания папки, чтобы ею           пользовались windows user`s.

Работаю с virtualbox, network NAT на ubuntu server and windows 7.

Привожу конфиг smb.conf:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba server %v
netbios name = smbserver
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no
[MyShare]
path = /home/smbshare/all
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

Так вот, винда вообще не видит папки `/ \\myserver`, я указал netbios name.

Comment: У вас в конфиге написано:

    netbios name = smbserver

Вы пытаетесь зайти по адресу `\\myserver`?

Comment: я просто изменил конфиг на http://hashcode.ru/questions/16098/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC-linux-%D0%B8%D0%B7-windows

и все равно не работает

Comment: Давайте с самого начала. До виртуальной машины linux идут пинги из windows?

Comment: ubuntu server и windows 7 запущены на виртуалке, сеть NAT, 
ifconfig | perl -nle'/dr:(\S+)/ && print $1'

выдает:
10.0.2.15 ping ok
192.168.122.1 ping ((

пингует

Comment: Вы хоть напишите, какой адрес у windows, какой у ubuntu. Грустный смайлик значит что пингов нет?
Зачем в обсуждении использовать конструкции типа ifconfig | perl -nle'/dr:(\S+)/ && print $1', когда от Вас требуется всего лишь ifconfig и ping. Или вы ждете помощи от perl-программиста?

Comment: ubuntu - inet addr: 10.0.2.15
windows (тот же ип)

извините, но что-то я туплю

Comment: Настройте для начала сеть для виртуальных машин. Можно сначала выполнить тестирование, соединив машины без NAT. Используйте тип подключения "Виртуальный адаптер хоста" или "Внутренняя сеть".

Comment: сеть упала на ubuntu с "Внутренняя сеть" и на винде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убедитесь, что на вашу шару есть права на чтение и выполнение для "other". Добавить необходимые права можно, выполнив:

```
chmod o+rx /home/smbshare/all
```